# Error retrieving table list on Sparx Enterprise Architect ODBC Postgres

Tags: postgresql, enterprise-architect

I'm trying to import DB from ODBC Postgres on Sparx Enterprise Architect.
I have followed the step on this [link](https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/10/projects_and_teams/setupapostgresqlodbcdriver.html) but still not able to Import DB with error : "Error retrieving table list"  like image below:

[image: Error retrieving table list]

But i able to Query to DB
[image: Able to query]

My detail environment are:

1. EA version 14
2. PostgreSQL 11.2, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit
3. ODBC Postgres 32 bit version 9.00.01.00

Comment: Might be a rights issue. Does your user has maximum rights in the database?

Comment: im using postgres as superuser on postgres, which user you mean?

Comment: I am facing same issue in version 15. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue connecting as a superuser in a similar environment:

1. EA 14
2. PostgreSQL 11.4
3. ODBC driver Postgres 32 bit Unicode v11.01.00.00

Inspired by this discussion [on the Sparx Systems forum](https://www.sparxsystems.com/forums/smf/index.php?topic=39841.0) I played with the Import DB Schema Object Filters until the table list was returned. The 'Procedures' and 'Functions' filters had to be set to 'false':
[image: here]

Comment: The ablove solution is not working with PostgreSQL 12 & EA 15

Comment: EA Sparx system 13, 14 & 15 with PostgreSQL 10 works well. With PostgreSQL 11 and above, the database comparison is not working. It seems like a bug in EA Sparx System

Comment: Worked for me DB2z/OS

Answer (score 0):

I've checked and I'm sure that the problem was solved with EA 15.2.

I have two versions of EA on different computers in the same network.
EA 15.0 has problems with importing database structure from PGSQL 13, but EA 15.2 imports it with no questions asked.